# Displaying several currencies in product details page

Tags: currency, magento-1.9, multicurrency

Please check the screen shot.
[image: currency]

I've allowed INR, EUR and USD in magento shop. I want to display appropriate price values of all allowed currencies for a product. 
Example: If the EUR value is €16.98, then appropriate USD and INR values will be $23.00 and Rs1,388.63 respectively (based on webserviceex values). I want all 3 values to be displayed in product details page. I also want to add 2 more attributes Price(EUR) and Price(INR) for prices tab in backend. How to do that?

Comment: Contact a Magento agency to make you an offer...

Comment: @mpaepper: I want to do that myself